# Transform a key, value object to values only array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, mongodb, mongoose

What is the best way to transform a `key : value` object to values only array in Javascript? I'm trying to perform a mongoose query using `$in`. As far as I know, I need to transform this:

```
[ { "key": "54ce3bef2d1ce6a82c90ccc3" }, { "key": "54d290a23eff5da01d05fe53" } ]
```

to this:

```
[ "54ce3bef2d1ce6a82c90ccc3", "54d290a23eff5da01d05fe53" ]
```

Should I loop through the first one and then create the second one in the loop? Or should I use some `map` function (eg. `$.map()`)? Is it wise to perform this operation client side or should I do all the work server side? Source object can grow as much as a few thousand pairs.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this quickly for known keys with `Array.prototype.map`

```
var arr = [{"key": "54ce3bef2d1ce6a82c90ccc3"}, {"key": "54d290a23eff5da01d05fe53"}];

arr = arr.map(function (e) {return e.key;});
// ["54ce3bef2d1ce6a82c90ccc3", "54d290a23eff5da01d05fe53"]
```

---

If the key is unknown but you know there is only one per item, combine with a `for..in`

```
arr = arr.map(function (e) {
    var key;
    for (key in e) // may also want to Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty here
        return e[key];
});
// ["54ce3bef2d1ce6a82c90ccc3", "54d290a23eff5da01d05fe53"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Tough call, but my first inclination would be to do a loop, but do you have to worry about duplicates?  Below does not account for that...

```
var arrayToStoreValues = [];
$.each(queryReturnSet,function(i,e){
     arrayToStoreValues[i] = e.key;
});
```

Comment: No duplicates. I decided to use `arr.map` approach. But still not sure which is better from performance perspective. Also not sure about doing this in an angular controller or in the node side is better.